# My images are not sharper Nikon D800

Tags: post-processing, sharpness, in-camera-processing, nikon-d800

I have Nikon D800 and I feel that my images are not sharper. My friend has D4 and I like the way his images look. But he always says he reduced the sharpness in the camera.

1. What value can I set to the sharpness of my camera (in camera settings).
2. What are the values that I can change in camera but can recover in post.

Thank you,
Tamil

Comment: Could you include a link to some example images that you feel aren't sharp?

Comment: are you comparing these images WITH THE SAME LENS? as that is the only way to compare the sharpness of a sensor.
I have a D800 and it is EXTREMELY sharp, but this is lens-dependent.

Comment: When you say "not sharper", do you mean "not sharper than your friend's images" or "not sharper than what you expect"?

Comment: i also have the same problem. my D700 looks sharper than the D800. i shoot the same lens. when i expand on the picture on the screen, the D700 pictures is sharper than the D800. i think is the A/F. i had the same problem with the D700 before i had it service. so i taking my D800 for service so they can check on the A/F. i hope that it will solve the problem.. i will keep you guys update..by the way i shoot nikon 24-70mm f2.8

Comment: Have you look at performing AF Fine tune on your lens? I know that my D800 has a tendency to backfocus resulting in un-sharp photos.

Comment: This is almost certainly a dupe of one of the many other "why aren't my images sharp" questions, but for some reason I can't find the main "why aren't my images sharp" question that we normally close as dupe on.  Short story answer for Tamil though, it likely isn't the sharpness setting that is the problem, but something with technique.  Possibly focus issues, possibly camera shake, possibly any of a number of other things already covered around the site and there isn't enough detail here to point you more specifically to your exact issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camera body will impact auto-focus speed, but most of the sharpness is going to come from the lens rather than the camera body.  Throw a sharp lens on a 5 year old DSLR and it will likely look sharper than a kit lens on a brand spanking new high end camera.  The camera can only capture the image projected on the sensor.  If that isn't sharp, neither will the photo that the camera captures.

Sharpness is primarily a result of the lens characteristics and proper focus.  Sharpening can also be applied as an image processing step.  If you shoot JPEG, then a setting in camera will adjust how it is processed on the fly.  If you shoot RAW (which I highly recommend for numerous reasons) then you capture raw sensor data and can apply sharpening very precisely in post production.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I shoot wedding so I use 24-70 F2.8 most of the time. I shoot in aperture priority at f 2.8 and auto iso (max 3400) and shutter speed not less than 1/80 (set this under auto iso in D800). When I mean images are not sharper I mean when I open both my image and my friends image my friends image look sharper and crisper at 100% zoom. I know that 36 MP plays a role here but I am thinking of some setting that I can do in camera (which can be reverted in post if not needed). I'll upload some pictures and post the link here

Comment: @Tamil - the D800 and a 24-70f/2.8 should be incredibly sharp.  Are you sure it isn't a technique issue?  Hand held at 1/80 and ISO 3400 you are going to start getting some reduction in sharpness and possibly some blur from shutter speed.  What kind of lens is your friend using?  If his shutter speed is faster or his ISO lower, then it isn't really an apples to apples comparison.  Ideally you want to test on the same lens, with the same settings with the same lighting on the same scene to really see the impact.  Also, try and match the level of detail rather than simple sharpness.

Comment: Since you have more resolution, you may look less sharp when pixel peeping but actually be more sharp overall since you are resolving smaller details in your resolution.  If you are only worried about the JPEG preview, simply setting the sharpness up should alter the preview produced, but that isn't going to be used when you open them up later in Lightroom (it might be if you open it in Nikon's software for RAW processing).

Comment: May be you are right. I think i look at pixel level and feel so. My friend is also using 24-70 f2.8 lens at 2.8 but fixed ISO at 1000 and he shoots in full manual.

Comment: I am still learning and may be my pictures and the way I evaluate them get better. Is there a setting that you suggest for me I mean the values in camera like sharpess, saturation etc.

Comment: @Tamil - sharpness and saturation only impact JPEGs and previews, they have no impact on the RAW processing done in programs like Lightroom and have no permanent impact.  Don't worry about those settings in camera at all.  You will get much better results tweaking them in post production and the in camera settings won't impact the actual raw data at all.  They just might be respected as the default settings by Nikon's raw processing software if you are using Nikon's toolset (which really isn't the best option available).

Comment: If you are new, I'd also suggest trying a staged test using a tripod and the same shutter settings.  It sounds like your friend is more experienced and so you are likely experiencing issues related to moving your camera while shooting.  At 35mp it is VERY sensitive to any motion while shooting, particularly at 1/80 shutter speeds.  This is probably the most likely source of your problems if you are a new shooter.  The D800 is a great camera, but it is not forgiving for beginners.  Full frame is much less forgiving in terms of focus and high megapixel counts are much less forgiving for shake.

Comment: Thank you. i'll do a staged test. Sounds like I am bad at evaluating the images :) so let me learn more and get back.

Comment: @Tamil - not bad I'd say, just there are a lot of factors to consider and it's hard to evaluate them without a lot of controls.  It's easy to think that photography is just pointing a camera in a direction and pushing a button, but there is actually a lot to it when you really get in to it.  You'll learn as you get more experienced, just like the rest of us did (and still do).

Answer (score 0):

The higher resolution of the D800 (7,360 × 4,912) means when you view at 100% you are actually more zoomed in than the D4 (4928 × 3280). Camera shake is exaggerated and to a lesser extent limits to your len's resolution.

Try re-sampling your images to the same resolution and compare them.